# Multiple KendoMultiSelect hangs page on initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-multiselect

I need to initialize multiple KendoMultiSelect in loop on my page (around 30 controls). but when it initializes, my page hangs until all controls finished their initialization. I tried with KendoComboBox and it worked smoothly. Please help me to workout on this issue with KendoMultiSelect. Thanks.

```
for (var i = 0; i < controls.length; i++) {
    $('#' + controls[i].controlId).kendoMultiSelect({
      placeholder: '--Select--',
      dataTextField:'Description',
      dataValueField: 'Id',
      autoBind: true,
      dataSource: data
    });
}
```

Comment: What's that 'data' you have as dataSource?

Comment: Where does it come from? Webservice? Database query?

Comment: I've datasource stored locally for all controls